# Angular Subjects/Observable Not updating on .next()

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new to Angular (using Angular 12) and trying to understand where I've gone haywire in my implementation.

I am trying to do a simple update to the user object.

In my auth Service, I have:

```
private userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IUserAuth | null>(null);
public user!: Observable<IUserAuth | null>; 

decodedToken: any;
baseUri = environment.baseURI + '/auth/';
jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
  private userService: UserService,
  private router: Router
) {
  this.userId$ = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(localStorage.getItem('_uid'));
  this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IUserAuth | null>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('_user') || '{}'));
  this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
}

public updateUser(id: string) {
  if (id != null) {
    this.userService.getUser(id)
      .subscribe(
        (user: IUser) => {
          if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('_user', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.userSubject.next(user);
          }
        }
      )
  }
}
```

In a component, after a successful call to update the user, I call:

```
if (data) {
  this.userNameModel.name = data.userName;
  this.auth.updateUser(data.id);
}
```

this should: call the update user method in auth service (it does), which fetches the user, passes on the latest properties to the next method, and updates local storage (verified).

In my navbar, I have:

```
user!: IUserAuth | null; 
signedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>

constructor(private auth: AuthService,  private router: Router) {
  this.signedIn$ = this.auth.signedIn$;
  this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
    this.user = user;
  })
}
```

and html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-dark clickable" (click)="routeToUserSettings()">{{user?.userName}}</a>
</li>
```

but the html username in the navbar isn't getting updated appropriately even though it should be watching for changes to the user object from the auth service...any help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribing to the `user` observable in `auth` service, subscribe to the `userSubject` observable:

```
this.auth.userSubject.subscribe(user => {
    this.user = user;
})
```

Your `userSubject` observable is receiving the next value, not the `user` observable.

Below are the changes to render the data returned from the observable within the authentication service:

In the `auth` Service re-declare the `userSubject` property as follows:

```
userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IUser | null>(null);
```

In your navbar component's `ngOnInit()` call the user update `updateUser()` within your `auth` service, then subscribe or apply an async pipe to the `userSubject` observable within the `auth` service:

1. Using Subscribe:

   TS:

   ```
   userName$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

   ...

   this.auth.updateUser('1'); 

   this.auth.userSubject.subscribe((user) => {
     this.user = user;
     console.log('user=' + user.id);
     console.log('user=' + user.userName);
     this.userName$.next(user.userName);
   });
   ```

   In your navbar component's HTML, subscribe to the `userName$`
   observable as follows:

   HTML:

   ```
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link text-dark clickable">
           {{ userName$ | async }} 
       </a>
   </li>
   ```
2. Using an Async Pipe:

   TS:

   ```
    user$: Observable<IUser>;  

    ...

    this.user$ = this.auth.userSubject.  
      pipe(map((user: IUser) => {
      console.log('user=' + user.id);
      console.log('user=' + user.userName);
      return user;  
    })
   ```

   );

   HTML:

   ```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark clickable">
          {{ (user$ | async).userName }} 
        </a>
    </li>
   ```

The above two methods will display the user name from the user data
returned from the user service.

Comment: then what is the point of userSubject being private per other resources on how to do this?

Comment: I did try this and it still didn't work.

Comment: Answer has been extended to cover usage of an async observable to render the user obtained from the auth service.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused why you're calling the .next in the navbar component subscription callback from the usersubject instead of the auth service itself.

Comment: You can use both alternatives. I have included another in the answer.